What currently determines Priority in MobileConnect when you use a Mobile Import Activity?
If I set up a daily import of records from a DE into MobileConnect, but some of those record IDs (in this case, mapped to the Contact Key) share the same phone number, how does that affect the "Priority" in the MobileConnect Demographics status? Is there a benefit to manually mapping the "Priority" field when you set up an import to MobileConnect?
I'm seeing some old questions that address this, but I'm not sure if any of that information is up to date. Thanks!

On a level of a single person it's the order in which the numbers were imported.
Imagine this situation:

You have Anna with phone number 4321. It's her only number and thus has priority 1
Anna changes her phone number to 2468. The change is reflected in your source system (like SF or wherever you import contact data from)
You set up an import automation with no number specified in the Priority field. The new number (2468) gets imported and since it's the newest record bound to Anna's ContactId it will get priority = 1, while the previous number (4321) will get its priority lowered to 2.

Is there any point in setting the priority in the import? I don't really think so.
Now, be mindful that this prioritization works only on a level of single contact. So it is perfectly normal for two contacts to have the same number defined as priority 1 in Marketing Cloud. This can cause some pain when your source system has logic that a phone number can only be assigned to one person (I saw such Sales Cloud setups).
